# Symfony 4 Component Process pass arguments for command

Tags: command-line, command, symfony4

**Symfony Component Process**

```php
/**
     * @param array          $command The command to run and its arguments listed as separate entries
     * @param string|null    $cwd     The working directory or null to use the working dir of the current PHP process
     * @param array|null     $env     The environment variables or null to use the same environment as the current PHP process
     * @param mixed|null     $input   The input as stream resource, scalar or \Traversable, or null for no input
     * @param int|float|null $timeout The timeout in seconds or null to disable
     *
     * @throws LogicException When proc_open is not installed
     */
    public function __construct($command, string $cwd = null, array $env = null, $input = null, ?float $timeout = 60)
    { .. }
```

I have created a command and I use the component Process in my controller.
When I try to run Process I get a ProcessFailException
The command "app:load-file foo bar foobar" failed
Exit Code: 1(General error)
.. ErrorOutput: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

```php
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

..
public function loadFile(KernelInterface $kernel) 
{
   $argument1 = 'foo';
   $argument2 = 'bar';
   $argument3 = 'foobar';
   $rootDir = $kernel->getProjectDir();
   $process = new Process(array(
      $rootDir . '/bin/console app:load-file',
      $argument1,
      $argument2,
      $argument3
   ));
   
   $process->mustRun();
}
```

What is the correct syntax to run the command from the controller ?
/* *@param array          $command The command to run and its arguments listed as separate entries
public function __construct($command, string $cwd = null, array $env = null, $input = null, ?float $timeout = 60)
{ .. }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$cwd is the second parameter of the constructor.

```php
   $argument1 = 'foo';
   $argument2 = 'bar';
   $argument3 = 'foobar';
   $rootDir = $kernel->getProjectDir();
   $process = new Process(
      "bin/console app:load-file $argument1 $argument2 $argument3",
      $rootDir
   );

   try {
      $process->mustRun();
   } catch(ProcessFailedException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $argument1 = 'foo';
 $argument2 = 'bar';
 $argument3 = 'foobar';
 $rootDir = $kernel->getProjectDir();
 $process = new Process(
     [
         $_SERVER['_'],
         'bin/console'
         'app:load-file',
         $argument1,
         $argument2,
         $argument3,
     ],
     $rootDir
 );

$process->mustRun();
```

`$_SERVER['_']` contains path to PHP interpreter executable. Use it if you have several php versions on the server